# Can a java module call a c module?

Tags: java, c, module, call

Just out of interest , is it possible to call a C module from a java module ? If so , how to do that ?

Comment: Thank you all , I just wanted to give it a try.. now that there's so much talk about inter-operability :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can use [Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jni/) to do this:

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it.  Whether you *should* do it is another matter.

On the pro side:

- Calling C libraries from Java will avoid the need to recode the libraries in Java (but see below).
- For some computational intensive algorithms, a well-written C implementation *may* be faster than an equivalently well-written Java version.
- Some operating system specific operations cannot be implemented in pure Java.

On the con side:

- There is a greater overhead in making a JNI call versus a simple Java method call.
- If your C library is not thread-safe, you have to be really careful calling it from Java.  And as a rule, C libraries are not implemented with thread safety in mind.
- If your C library has memory management issues, it may destabilize the Java platform resulting in JVM crashes.
- Calling native libraries immediately means that your application is harder to port, and requires a more complicated build process.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you call C/C++ from Java using the Java Native Interface ([JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)) from this purpose.

- [Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)

You can also use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) for this purpose:

- [SWIG Tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look into [JNI (Java Native Interface).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As others have already mentioned, JNI or Java Native Interface is Sun's preferred way of doing this. If you feel you'll need to call the C code from other languages as well as Java, I'd look into [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which will transparently generate the JNI code for you, but also allow you to do similar things with, for example, Python.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [C to (Java) bytecode compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#C_to_bytecode_compilers), which may be able to turn your C code into a .jar of portable Java classes you can call directly from Java.

Detriments versus JNI:

- There is a noticeable performance penalty, typically at least 100%.

Benefits versus JNI:

- Just like running pure Java code, it is safe, does not require special privileges to load, and does not require recompiling for every target platform.

(When I say "[JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)" I really mean all Java interfaces to native code.  For example, the same applies to [CNI](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html).)

Comment: Another detriment versus JNI is that you won't be able to do platform specific things this way ... and that's (IMO) the most important use-case for C libraries.