# How can I use c functions on my java

Tags: java, c

I have 100 of different image processing algorithms written using c. I want to use those function and library created using c to my java project. How can I reuse those functions and library on my java project.

Comment: Look at using the Java Native Interface. It's surprisingly simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a java module call a c module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082265/can-a-java-module-call-a-c-module)

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna do this then go for advanced options like ***web services(SOAP)***. Make a web service, export those methods and use it in Java.

*As far as I understand the most popular free solution is gSOAP* http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Deepak. Can I even export the dll as well?

Comment: I think by SOAP you can only export the methods but if those methods are using the objects of other classes then those classes will also exported as well. I am talking in terms of Java but the concept is same for every language. You have to just make the web service and export the methods other dependencies are managed itself. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Native Interface

Check:

- http://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/CallingCLibraryRoutinesfromJava.pdf
- http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at JNR and JNA if you find JNI difficult

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013nutter-2013526.pdf

https://github.com/jnr

https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html

JNA is a bit slow so I wouldn't recommend it for time critical applications.  The new Java standard is rumoured to have a variant of JNR or JFFI (Java Native Runtime Foreign Function Interface) built in.

Comment: There is also JNR-FFI as an option.